# How do I cache something within a request in EWL?

Tags: c#, caching, data-access-layer, enterprise-web-library

What's the best practice for caching data within a request?

More specifically, let's say I a have a table with several rows of data and each row needs to do a separate database query to get details on a Bakery. I know that by the end of the request I will have to get data on each individual Bakery in Boston. I'd like to select all Bakeries I need in one shot before I add data to the table so I have them.

1) If I do BakeriesTableRetrieval.GetRows( new BakeriesTableEqualityCondition.CityId( CityIds.Boston ) ), will database caching magically not have to make a round trip when I later do BakeriesTableRetrieval.GetRowMatchingId( idOfSomeBakeryInBoston )?

2) Assuming 1 is false or that I have a different situation where I just need to cache my own stuff, how do I best keep my own pre-request cache?

Answer (score 1):

My answers below apply when you are using EWL's own web framework (EWF), or if you are otherwise inside a `DataAccessState.Current.ExecuteWithCache` block.

1. Yes, database caching will automatically eliminate those single-row queries, as long as you are using Table Retrieval. With Query Retrieval, you can accomplish the same thing if you implement the `updateSingleRowCaches` partial method.
2. Use `DataAccessState.Current.GetCacheValue`.

Comment: Small wrinkle in why #1 doesn't work. I'm not querying by the primary key, I'm querying by a pair of values that is unique. Does #1 work with complex primary keys? If I made the table have that tuple as its primary key instead of having a separate single one would it help auto-caching?

Comment: @GregSmalter: I don't think #1 currently supports complex primary keys.